# How to process incoming custorm headers in http request and then reverse proxy the request depend on the result

Tags: nginx

I am newbie for Nginx, my requirement is pretty much like this:

I set up Nginx as an front end service before my service, that's like an reverse proxy server, while I need any incoming http request be handled based on incoming customer headers. I know I can set reverse proxy like following:

```
server {
    listen      18080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /myService {
            proxy_pass http://host:port/myservice/;
    }
```

}

I also know getting incoming "my-header" from incoming request by using $http_my_header, what i need is, retrieve the "my-header" from request, and call another remote web service like “http: //authserver:authport/authorize” with "my-header" in request header, and authserver will authorize the "my-header" and reply a JSON based response like:

```
{
   valid: "true"/"false";
}
```

then I need to based on the response "valid" value to decide proxy_pass the request to myservice behind nginx or direct deny with 403 http response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to issue a subrequest in terms of nginx.

You may do it using one of Eval modules and then parse response by regexp, but it is not recommended.

The recommended way is to use http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule.
Take a look at http://openresty.org nginx bundle.

```
init_by_lua 'require "cjson"';

location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://authserver:12345/authorize;
}
location /myService {
    access_by_lua '
        res = ngx.location.capture("/auth")
        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
            local response = cjson.decode( res.body )
            if response.valid and response.valid == "true" then
                return
            end
        end
        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
    ';
    proxy_pass http://host:port/myservice/;
}
```

Note that subrequests issued by ngx.location.capture inherit all the request headers of the current request by default.

Comment: Thanks. The example you provide is like request is sending to authserver and based on auth result, nginx decide proxy_pass to myservice or not. If the request is directly to myservice and I just want it be authorized by authserver before it proxy_pass?

Comment: @Jim Song Sorry, didn't see your comment. You are wrong, location is /myService so request is directly to myService. I issue the subrequest to authserver