# How to look for a certain header in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as a proxy server to basically serve image files and hand off everything else to another server at port 9000.

What I want to do is have nginx return an HTTP 500 error code if the incoming request does not contain a specific header (X-AUTH-TOKEN), but only if the requests are not for the resources "/register" or "/events". In that case, they need to go straight to port 9000.

Here's the configuration I currently have:

```
http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream my-backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # main ngingx server
    server {
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://my-backend;
        }

        location /images/ {
            root /home/images;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to implement this kind of logic? Thanks.

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319869/how-to-process-incoming-custorm-headers-in-http-request-and-then-reverse-proxy-t)

The recommended way is to use http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule. Take a look at http://openresty.org nginx bundle.

Comment: @henrique, please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is native HttpCoreModule feature exists:
You can check any header exists/match by something like this:

```
location /blah {
    if ( $http_x_auth_token ) {
        // do something, allow
    }
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER

Hope it will help :)